# Enable postgis for an existing RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-rds

How can I install or enable postgis to do spatial queries for an existing database instance that already has data stored inside it? I have come across a few tutorials like this one that seem to suggest that the database needs to be empty before installing postgis with the CREATE EXTENSION statement.
http://technobytz.com/install-postgis-postgresql-9-3-ubuntu.html

The postgresql version of my instance is 9.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the recommendation of the postgresql irc, I used CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA postgis; creating the extension in the same schema as your app could also work

Answer (score 0):

```
psql -d your_db_name -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis--2.1.1.sql
```

It's point 5 in your cited [tutorial](http://technobytz.com/install-postgis-postgresql-9-3-ubuntu.html).

Comment: I am not sure whether or not I can gain access to the file system of the RDS instance to be able to run that command. If I was to take the alternative route of installing a matching postgis version on ec2, I am not sure what kind of implications running that command using a version of postgis that was not compiled with the same features as the one on the RDS instance will have. could you address these concerns that I have?